# Codeigniter: Error in Loader class after updating to CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently updated my project to CI4 and also updated my WAMP to the latest version.

But my project hasn't worked since. There is `MY_Controller` class that is inherited from `CI_Controller` placed in `application/core/`

It gives me this error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: The "Generator" class is reserved for internal use and cannot be manually instantiated

Filename: C:\wamp64\www\alnoor\system\core\Loader.php

Line Number: 1285

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\alnoor\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: C:\wamp64\www\alnoor\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Anybody knows what this means or how can I get it fixed?

This is the Loader class function:

```
protected function _ci_init_library($class, $prefix, $config = FALSE, $object_name = NULL)
    {
        // Is there an associated config file for this class? Note: these should always be lowercase
        if ($config === NULL)
        {
            // Fetch the config paths containing any package paths
            $config_component = $this->_ci_get_component('config');

            if (is_array($config_component->_config_paths))
            {
                $found = FALSE;
                foreach ($config_component->_config_paths as $path)
                {
                    // We test for both uppercase and lowercase, for servers that
                    // are case-sensitive with regard to file names. Load global first,
                    // override with environment next
                    if (file_exists($path.'config/'.strtolower($class).'.php'))
                    {
                        include($path.'config/'.strtolower($class).'.php');
                        $found = TRUE;
                    }
                    elseif (file_exists($path.'config/'.ucfirst(strtolower($class)).'.php'))
                    {
                        include($path.'config/'.ucfirst(strtolower($class)).'.php');
                        $found = TRUE;
                    }

                    if (file_exists($path.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/'.strtolower($class).'.php'))
                    {
                        include($path.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/'.strtolower($class).'.php');
                        $found = TRUE;
                    }
                    elseif (file_exists($path.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/'.ucfirst(strtolower($class)).'.php'))
                    {
                        include($path.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/'.ucfirst(strtolower($class)).'.php');
                        $found = TRUE;
                    }

                    // Break on the first found configuration, thus package
                    // files are not overridden by default paths
                    if ($found === TRUE)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $class_name = $prefix.$class;

        // Is the class name valid?
        if ( ! class_exists($class_name, FALSE))
        {
            log_message('error', 'Non-existent class: '.$class_name);
            show_error('Non-existent class: '.$class_name);
        }

        // Set the variable name we will assign the class to
        // Was a custom class name supplied? If so we'll use it
        if (empty($object_name))
        {
            $object_name = strtolower($class);
            if (isset($this->_ci_varmap[$object_name]))
            {
                $object_name = $this->_ci_varmap[$object_name];
            }
        }

        // Don't overwrite existing properties
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if (isset($CI->$object_name))
        {
            if ($CI->$object_name instanceof $class_name)
            {
                log_message('debug', $class_name." has already been instantiated as '".$object_name."'. Second attempt aborted.");
                return;
            }

            show_error("Resource '".$object_name."' already exists and is not a ".$class_name." instance.");
        }

        // Save the class name and object name
        $this->_ci_classes[$object_name] = $class;

        // Instantiate the class
        $CI->$object_name = isset($config)
            ? new $class_name($config)
            : new $class_name();
    }
```

The error is in the last statement.

Comment: Also when I don't use inheritance, I mean when the main controller extends CI_Controller, it still doesn't work, and gives the same error.

Comment: You need to be very aware that CI4 is completely different than CI3 and there's no real "upgrade path" between 3.x and 4.x. Most sites would need a complete (or at least, thorough) re-write, as opposed as for example moving from 3.1.0 to 3.1.11. A lot changed in CI4, including namespacing and a lot of internals, so the error you're seeing may just be the tip of the iceberg

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simpler than I thought.
It turns out CI4 has a new built in function called `Generator`, and in my old project I had a library with the same name.
So I changed the name to `My_generator`, and changed the code accordingly, and it worked out fine.